# How to hide the first row of my recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i want to know how i can hide the specified row in my recycler-row-layout. I specified my row in a seperate layout and it will show as the first row. 
thanks alot, ill rate your comments. sry for bad language.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: post your code to display items in recyclerview .

Answer (score 0):

you can define a flag on your model class, based on that flag in you adapter while overriding the "getView" method check either you want to display that particular row or not.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get the position of your Item and then remove it from RecyclerView List.

```
   int position = YOUR_RECYCLERVIEW_ITEM_POSITION;
   yourList.remove(position);
   yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To keep your data backed up somewhere, create another ArrayList. Get the item from your original list and add this item to the new list.

```
ObjectClass o = yourList.get(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

In [a simple example with RecyclerView](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/Planets/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/planets/MainActivity.java) decrease the returned number of items by 1 (since you hide 1 item):

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPlanets.length - 1;
}
```

And also adjust the displayed items (make a jump by 1 to skip the item at `mHiddenPosition`):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlanetViewHolder vh, int position) {
    int i = (position >= mHiddenPosition ? position + 1 : position);
    TextView tv = (TextView) vh.itemView;
    tv.setText(mPlanets[i]);
    tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(24);
    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_stars_black_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: im not sure if i understand right, but the first row of my recycler isnt a element of my arraylist. its just the specified row_layout

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how i can hide the specified row in my recycler-row-layout

Suggestions:

If you want to hide before appearing the list:

1. Before passing list of items to recycler view Adapter class, delete object available at specified position in the list.
2. Now object at specified position will not appear in the recyclerview.

If you want to hide after appearing the list:

1. Create a  Hide button on recycler-item-layout.
2. Attach a listener to it.
3. Inside `onClick()` delete item at specified position from list (it may be arraylist) and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.